# What plugin or jquery carasoul is used

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I was working on one website. I found this http://www.yogyogurt.co.uk/takehome jquery(which is used to display the products). I want to know if someone know about this plugin or jquery what is its name?

Thank you! (In advance)

Answer (score 0):

as I saw in its page, they use the bootstap carousel plugin:

https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/6155151

You can use it as:

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#recipeCarousel.carousel').carousel({
          interval: false
        });
        jQuery("#recipeCarousel .carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
        jQuery("#recipeCarousel .carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");

});
```

Comment: No its not layer slider :( They dont have any API integrated for that.

Comment: They include the script: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.yogyogurt.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js?ver=4.1.1'></script>`

Comment: Is there any way i can create this jquery?

Comment: You want that down one? (in the botton of the page) or the first one? with the yogo pots (this first is the bootstrap carousel standard) https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/6155151.

Comment: Bottom one...where they are showing products and click on each of the product its description opens up.

Comment: They use 2 carousel plugins, I edit my anware, maybe it can help